# ConstraintLayout misbehaviour

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

This is my dialog,

```
public class TestDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_dialog, container, false);
    }
}
```

When I am using `RelativeLayout` for my design like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp48"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/trebuchet"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test Dialog"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTitle"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_public_24px"
        android:tint="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        android:fontFamily="@font/trebuchet"
        android:text="This is very long text, This is very long text, This is very long text" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView_close"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/close"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24dx"
        android:text="@string/cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting this output.

[image]

But When I am using ConstraintLayout for my design like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp48"
        android:fontFamily="@font/trebuchet"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test Dialog"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTitle"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_public_24px"
        android:tint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/trebuchet"
        android:text="This is very long text, This is very long text, This is very long text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTitle" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView_close"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/close"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24dx"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am getting following output.

[image]

I don't know why this strange behavior. Only in dialog I am getting this behavior.

If anything I'm missing in constraint layout, please let me know friends, I'll correct myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is set Theme to your dialog.

```
 @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.dialog;
    }
```

**style**

```
<style name="dialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/radius</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">80%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">85%</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

**radius.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in your ConstraintLayout tag. Since a Dialog has no fixed width, using `match_parent` won't work. Maybe you could set a fixed width, or a minimum width.

Comment: I don't know, but if you put your code in an empty activity it's not stretched, so the problem is outside. Maybe RelativeLayout has different rules for laying out such components. I never really used it

Comment: This one also good solution, but its better to use width/height as percentage instead of fixing it.

Answer (score -1):

First, it's not the `ConstraintLayout` but how you are implementing the `Dialog` itself. It's a suggestion and according to [Dialog Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs):

> The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid
>   instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following
>   subclasses:
>
> `AlertDialog`
>   A dialog that can show a title, up to three buttons, a
>   list of selectable items, or a custom layout.
>
> `DatePickerDialog or TimePickerDialog`
>   A dialog with a pre-defined UI that allows the user
>   to select a date or time.

So basically you'll be using `setView` api:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity());
    // Setting my layout here
    builder.setView(R.layout.my_layout);
    builder.setPositiveButton(/* My Methods */)
           .setNegativeButton(/* My Methods */);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Read about it in [Creating a Custom Layout documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#CustomLayout). If you want more customization then create a custom theme within `values` > `styles.xml` which can be used throughout the app or just by setting it along with the builder, like:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity(), R.style.My_Alert_Dialog_Theme);
```

Comment: So, you are saying like we should not use DialogFragment, right?

Comment: Not directly, instead, extend it and then override `onCreateDialog` and there, return an instance of AlertDialog as shown above, or follow the links for more info.

Comment: Question is about `DialogFragment`, your comment is about `Dialog`. It is not the same thing.